# Sort combobox alphabetically

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sorting, combobox

To begin, yes I've searched and saw the other articles regarding this and not they don't help.

I have a very simple code and I just need to sort the combo box after I populate it.

So far I have this:

```
    'Doctor comboBox
    For Each doc As Doctor In DoctorList
        CBX_Doctors.Items.Add(doc.FirstName + " " + doc.LastName)
    Next
```

I need to sort it by first name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `OrderBy` clause on your object. This predicate will order them by the field given.

```
For Each doc As Doctor In DoctorList.OrderBy(Function(o) o.FirstName)
    CBX_Doctors.Items.Add(doc.FirstName + " " + doc.LastName)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

After you add your list, use `CBX_Doctors.Sorted = True`.  Like this:

```
For Each doc As Doctor In DoctorList
    CBX_Doctors.Items.Add(doc.FirstName + " " + doc.LastName)
Next

CBX_Doctors.Sorted = True
```