# ListBox past edge of Panel

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Here's photo of the form showing the listbox stopping at the edge of the panel when it should extend up past it. I have a project with several panels and a datagridview.  I also have some textboxes and buttons. when I click on one of the textboxes, I have a listbox set to be shown and and rezise and locate to just above the textbox but the size I want it to expand to goes beyond the panel and datagrid and that part is not visible.

I've set it to "bring to front" but that doesn't solve the problem

[image]

```
Private Sub txtPayee_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtPayee.Click
  ListPayee.Show()
  ListPayee.BringToFront()
  ListPayee.Left = txtPayee.Left
  ListPayee.Height = 200
  ListPayee.Width = txtPayee.Width
  ListPayee.Top = txtPayee.Top - ListPayee.Height
End Sub
```

Comment: We can't see the code or the form you are talking about.

Comment: how do I attach a photo or code? This is my first time using this site.

Comment: I added your code so please delete that code comment.  Controls can't escape their parent boundaries, at least not visibly.  It sounds like you should be using a ComboBox instead anyway.

Comment: I would but the combobox or list box will be databound and you can't sort a combox.  Ive tried before setting the data in the database to be sorted but when it shows in a combo box it's not. that's why I was using a list box.

Comment: You've turned this into an XY problem.  That is, the populating of your ComboBox is the real issue, not this hidden ListBox.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand.  Is there a way to sort the combobox ?

Comment: @rjadams02 Does [Sort combobox alphabetically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26820188/sort-combobox-alphabetically) help?

Comment: No but I found an answer to sorting a databound combobox on Google that worked. Thanks for your patience with me! 
 MoneyPlusBindingSource.Sort = "Payee"
  cbpayee.DataSource = MoneyPlusBindingSource